# How use variable dataset twice in SSIS package

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I use recordset destination for create dataset in variable.
Later use variable readonly in Script Component(source), but when I try use this variable in other Script Component(source) get empty dataset. I think first Script Component blocked my variable, don't understand how fix it.

```
VariableDispenser variableDispenser = (VariableDispenser)this.VariableDispenser;
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("User::dsOrganization");
        IDTSVariables100 vars;
        variableDispenser.GetVariables(out vars);

        OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var ds = vars["User::dsOrganization"].Value;
        oleDA.Fill(dt, ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.Organization = dr["Organization"].ToString();
            Output0Buffer.OrganizationCode = dr["OrganizationCode"].ToString();
            Output0Buffer.SPOrganizationCode = dr["SPOrganizationCode"].ToString();
            Output0Buffer.SPOrganizationMember = dr["SPOrganizationMember"].ToString();
        }
        vars.Unlock();
```

Two Script Component use equal code first component get 44 rows second - none

If change Script Component to Script Task everything work right.

Comment: post code - there is no way we can figure out without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the pointer of the enumerator is at the end of your recordset when you try to loop through it a second time. Try cloning your recordset before loading it into a dataset.

However, loading large data sets into variables should be avoided. Try to evaluate and optimize the design of your flow.